# What's the point of a default gateway?

Tags: networking, router, ip, firewall

Maybe there's something I'm misunderstanding fundamentally, but this just isn't clicking.
I deal with networks that look like (Router > Firewall > Switch > Hosts) with a few port forwarding rules as well.

In my mind, each device (minus the switch since it's unmanaged) would have one IP to identify it, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

For simplicity let's say the router's IP (the public IP that identifies it on the ISP's giant network) is 1, the Firewall's is 2, and an example host is 3.

When setting up port forwarding, I would expect to forward 1 to 2 and then 2 to 3, and to access the web GUIs on 1 and 2 from 3, I would just have to type in 1 or 2's IP.

But then there's something called a default gateway... I understand it as the IP that the hosts are expected to send outbound packets to, but if that's the case, why wouldn't it just be 2?

Comment: How would hosts know that it is 2 without you telling them so?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually (in most cases) the firewall is just an ip-address filter between router and host.
The only reason it has an ip-address is that you can access its management interface.
The hosts in the system don't even know it is there (and they don't care). As far as they are concerned the router (== default gateway) handles outbound traffic.

And in most SOHO deployments the router and the firewall are actually a single device (the firewall is a function of the router itself) with a combined management interface and a single ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

Default gateway concerns outbound traffic. There is something like a network mask.

Let’s say your computer has 192.168.0.100. The network mask is 255.255.255.0, and the default gateway is 192.168.0.1.

Now your computer wants to connect to an IP 'X'. By applying the network mask on that address and applying the network mask to your IP, it now can be determined if 'X' can be reached directly (simply sending data to your local switch/hub/router (which usually also acts as switch) or if data must be sent to the gateway address, which then knows where to send the packets in order to reach the address.

Let’s say 'X' is 192.168.0.5. If you apply (bitwise 'AND') the mask to it, you get `192.168.0.0`
If you apply the mask to your own IP, you also get `192.168.0.0`. Those two are identical. Therefore the other IP is local, and needn’t go over the gateway.

Now let’s say 'X' is 123.123.123.123. Applying the mask once more, we get `123.123.123.0`. Comparing that to `192.168.0.0` (our own IP with the mask applied) says that the two are not identical. Therefore, the packet has to be sent to the default gateway (192.168.0.1) which knows where to pass along the packet in order to reach 123.123.123.123.